# Android opencv Camera resolution low

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera, javacameraview

So, I have implemented opencv to my android project, but when listing avaliable sizes for resolution I get the highest value of 1920x1080(im using Samsung Galaxy s6 Edge Plus). The highest resolution with default camera is 5312x2988, after that 3984x2988 and so on.

I have tried finding answer on the internet, but there is no explanation on how to do this and, if its not possible, why it isn't. Can someone help?

Im using OpenCV 3.2, Android Version 7.0

Comment: At least mention what version of OpenCV you are integrating.

Comment: @MorrisonChang updated, sorry for that

Comment: Android version? This doesn't concern OpenCV whatsoever

Comment: @RickM. Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device does not deliver its full camera capabilities through the deprecated camera API, which is supported for backwards compatibility with legacy apps. You should use the new camera2 API to unlock higher video resolutions. While the native interface to camera2 has been introduced recently, it is still not accommodated in OpenCV. Luckily, there is a [Java class](https://github.com/ctodobom/OpenCV-3.1.0-Android/blob/master/OpenCV/src/main/java/org/opencv/android/Camera2Renderer.java) that can help. An official [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dbd/tutorial_android_ocl_intro.html) shows how this new API can be used in your app.

Comment: Alright, so, I need to use Androids camera2 api and use OpenCv's Camera2Renderer?

Comment: Thank you for tutorial. I read that not all devices support OpenCL, with some of the flagships being unable to process it. Is this true, or can I use it with all phones?